# How to test jmeter's response and pass parameters?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am researching jmeter and I have a question.

[image: Login]

My first question: in case : (github )

```
input autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control input-block" id="login_field" name="login" tabindex="1" type="text"

input class="form-control form-control input-block" id="password" name="password" tabindex="2" type="password"
```

In case the website don't have field "name", how can I pass the param to website ? can we use css or xpath to pass the param to website ?

[image]

My second question:

How to test the response value from the site ? (from the picture the response data not right, still on login page)

Thanks for reading and supporting me to correct this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As per [HTML Forms article](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

   > **The Name Attribute**
   >
   > To be submitted correctly, each input field **must** have a name attribute.

   Actually you should't worry about HTML markup, JMeter acts on protocol level and provides record-and-replay functionality. See [Apache JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) for configuration instructions.
2. You can use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to add a check whether response is still login page or not. For example if the user is logged in - he shouldn't see username input any more. See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on conditionally failing JMeter samplers.

Comment: Hi Dmitri T, I want to write java code for Jmeter. i want to sent more action using different params for every thread. Thanks for your answer...

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T, can you give me some idea in this case ?